# PDO query failure

Tags: mysql, oop, pdo

I have a problem with my PDO class. I just have started learning OOP and I don't really know where I made a mistake

My class code:

```
<?php

class admin
{
  private $host = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db501865';
  private $username = 'root';
  private $password = 'root';
  private $conn;


  public function connect() {
      try {
          $conn = new PDO($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
      } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
          die( 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage() );
      }
      return $conn;
  }

  public function disconnect( $conn ) {
      $conn = '';
  }


  public function listReal()
    {
        $this ->connect();
        $real = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM `real`');
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($real as $row)
        {
            echo'<li><img src="'.$row['image'].'"></li>';
        }
        $real -> closeCursor();
        echo'</ul>';
    }

}
?>
```

and after executing following code I have 500 error in my browser.

```
$db = new admin;
$db -> listReal();
```

Where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$this->var_name` for your member variables.
Also there is no need to connect if you are already connected.

```
class admin
{
    private $host = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = 'local@pass';
    private $conn;


    public function connect() {
        if($this->conn) return;
        $this->conn = new PDO($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function disconnect( $conn ) {
        $conn = '';
    }


    public function listReal()
    {
        $this ->connect();
        $real = $this->conn->query('SELECT * FROM `real`');

        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($real as $row)
        {
            echo'<li><img src="'.$row['user_id'].'"></li>';
        }
        $real -> closeCursor();
        echo'</ul>';
    }

}
try{
    $db = new admin;
    $db -> listReal();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Now all I get is one <ul> in the source code. idk what it could be

Comment: I moved around the error handling a bit. You should be able to see the MySQL error (if any) now.

Comment: As far as I remember, you can't just foreach a PDOStatement like that.

Comment: Apparently you can. I didn't know that either and I don't know if it has any gotcha's, so i did't modify it.